# Date format in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to enter the date like this: 12/10/2016, but Excel keeps changing it to 10/12/2016, I have it as English in the format too but it keeps doing it.  Can anyone help?

Regards

Mick

Answer (score 2):

1. On the **Home** tab, in the **Number** group, click the Dialog Box Launcher next to **Number**.

[image]

You can also press CTRL+1 to open the Format Cells dialog box.

2. In the **Category** list, click **Date** or **Time**.

[image]

3. In the **Type** list, click the date or time format that you want to use.

> Note: Date and time formats that begin with an asterisk (*) respond to changes in regional date and time settings that are specified in Control Panel. Formats without an asterisk are not affected by Control Panel settings.

4. To display dates and times in the format of other languages, click the language setting that you want in the **Locale (location)** box.

[image]

The number in the active cell of the selection on the worksheet appears in the **Sample** box so that you can preview the number formatting options that you selected.

[image]